# Comparing dates in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to compare the current date with the date of the post in jekyll/liquid. If the current date is less than the date of the post, then I want to show the post title.

Here is my code so far:

```
 <header class="announce-ticker">
  <div class="container">
    {% capture currentDate %}
      {{ 'now' | date: '%s'}}
    {% endcapture %}
    {% assign eventCount = 0 %}
    {% assign eventPosts = site.posts %}
    {% for post in eventPosts %}
      {% capture postDate %}
        {{ post.date | date: '%s'}}
      {% endcapture %}
      {% if currentDate < postDate %}
        {% post.title %}
        {% assign eventCount = 1 %}
      {% endif %}
      {{ currentDate}}
      {{ postDate }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if eventCount == 0 %}
      <p>No events</p>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
</header>
```

My problem is that it's not showing the post when it is greater than current date.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Future dated posts are not published by default. Basic way to enable them through command line is to use the `future` option:

```
jekyll serve --future
```

Alternatively, you can add the `future` parameter to your `_config.yml`:

```
future: true
```

More options in [this article](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Working-with-upcoming-posts-in-Jekyll.html).

Comment: I also coerced the dates back into integers and it seemed to work as well!